# Error 1012 when using SSL in AFNetworking 2.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl, certificate, afnetworking-2

I'm trying to connect with SSL to my website which is using a certificated signed by StartSSL. When I browse to the website, everything is working fine, however, when I try to use SSL in the app, I get:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)" UserInfo=0x8d635f0 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://edutoets.nl/API/login.php, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://edutoets.nl/API/login.php}
```

I've included the certificate in .cer format (after converting it from .crt to .cer with openssl) in the app bundle and AFNetworking can find it. Here's my code that creates the security policy of the manager:

```
- (AFSecurityPolicy*) sslSecurityPolicy
{
    NSString *cerPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"edutoets" ofType:@"cer"];
    NSData *certData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:cerPath];
    AFSecurityPolicy *securityPolicy = [[AFSecurityPolicy alloc] init];
    [securityPolicy setAllowInvalidCertificates:NO];
    [securityPolicy setPinnedCertificates:@[certData]];
    [securityPolicy setSSLPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModeCertificate];

    return securityPolicy;
}
```

And here I set the security policy and execute the request:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager;
[manager setSecurityPolicy:[self dodyrwSecurityPolicy]];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
[manager POST:kLoginURL parameters:... success:...];
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. The .cer file looks fine (the certificate corresponds to the certificate when browsing to the website). This is happening on the iOS simulator.

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: I think I had a similar behavior (not sure if it was with StartSSL). The issue was that I was missing an intermediate certificate or something like that. Make sure on their usage instructions you're not going over it.

Comment: I've added the intermediate certificate and the root certificate and now it's working great! Thanks for the advice :)

Comment: Well, I guess you should add what you did as a response to the question and mark it as correct! Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, apparently you should also add your intermediate certificate and root certificate to the app bundle. Afer I did that, it started to work!

Comment: See the [`validatesCertificateChain`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/2.1.0/AFNetworking/AFSecurityPolicy.h#L47) property on AFSecurityPolicy which was added in 2.1.0.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar situation where I received error 1012 despite having a valid SSL cert embedded in my app. This app could communicate with the server (with everything else remaining the same) when using AFNetworking v1. My problem was caused by not having the entire chain of certificates embedded in the app. Setting `validatesCertificateChain = NO;` fixed the issue.

Comment: @SreekeshOkky Do the subsequent edits provide an answer?

Comment: Thanks for this answer; solved my problem, too. Do you think disabling this flag will make the app vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks?

Comment: I'm not a security expert so I can't comment on whether that this makes the app much more vulnerable. However, the app did pass a penetration test by a competent security professional with this setting. Take it for what you will.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this server-side — my server had a .crt file installed that didn't include all the intermediate certificates back to the root. You can `cat` together all the certificates into a .crt file and install that on the webserver.

I didn't have to change my app binary in any way. (Thank goodness!)

--

(This error is strange. The HTTPS problem didn't occur when using Safari or Chrome, and this error code is for 'user cancelled authentication'. But it's definitely an SSL problem.)