# AFNetworking POST Request not working?

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2

This question is already answered at many places but no solution is working for me! I m using code for `AFNetworking` as following

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer=[AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
NSDictionary *parameters=@{@"Key1":@"Value1",@"Key2":@"Value2"};
//    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"foo": @"bar"};
[manager POST:@"https://www.MyURL.com/index.php" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Error :

```
Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)" UserInfo=0x7a2a03b0 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.MyURL.com/index.php, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://www.MyURL.com/index.php}
```

I got no luck for above request.

I do not know what is wrong with my code in `POST` Request, `GET` Request is working fine in the `AFNetworking`.

Comment: ASIHTTPRequest has been no longer updated since 2011. Check [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/Setup-instructions)

Comment: @Prince: if you go to the https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request you will know that it has been updated 7 month before. I m converting my code to AFNetworking but POST request is not working that is why I asked help.

Comment: add Error in question so other can know whats problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one :

```
 NSDictionary *dictParameters = parameter here

 //create url
 NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"url here"];
 NSLog(@"loginurl : %@",strURL);

 AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

 manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

 AFHTTPRequestOperation *apiRequest = [manager POST:strURL parameters:dictParameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
 {
    NSData *jsonData = (NSData *)responseObject;

    NSError * parsedError = nil;

    id *value = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&parsedError];
    if (parsedError == nil)
    {
       //Successfull
    }
    else
    {
       NSLog(@"wrong while parsing json data");
    }
 }
 failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
 {
      NSLog(@"Error : %@",[error description]);
 }];

 //start request right now
 [apiRequest start];
```

**EDIT** : Just Formatted

Comment: Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)" UserInfo=0x7aef7b00 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.fantasyguru.com/ws/myguru/index.php, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://www.fantasyguru.com/ws/myguru/index.php}

Comment: 1)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11607214/nsurlerrordomain-error-1012 2)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22111801/ios-cant-perform-http-get-request-error-domain-nsurlerrordomain-code-1012 3)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22793054/error-1012-when-using-ssl-in-afnetworking-2-0